# ClamAV Anti-Virus not Classifying Virus Emails as Virus

Tags: sendmail, spamassassin, clamav, slackware, mailscanner

I have installed Sendmail as my SMTP mail server, SpamAssassin as Spam Classifier and ClamAV Anti-Virus. I tested out sending my server a virus email eicar.txt

Now I am receiving the virus email in my mail and not in the quarantine folder. To find out what's wrong, I runthe command below:

```
MailScanner --lint
```

The output is :

```
Trying to setlogsock(unix)

Reading configuration file /etc/MailScanner/MailScanner.conf
Reading configuration file /etc/MailScanner/conf.d/README
Read 868 hostnames from the phishing whitelist
Read 5807 hostnames from the phishing blacklists

Checking version numbers...
Version number in MailScanner.conf (5.1.3) is correct.

Your envelope_sender_header in spamassassin.conf is correct.

Checking for SpamAssassin errors (if you use it)...
Using SpamAssassin results cache
Connected to SpamAssassin cache database
SpamAssassin reported no errors.
mktemp: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: mktemp [-V] | [-dqtu] [-p prefix] [template]
Auto: Found virus scanners: clamav 
Connected to Processing Attempts Database
Created Processing Attempts Database successfully
There are 0 messages in the Processing Attempts Database
Using locktype = posix
MailScanner.conf says "Virus Scanners = auto"
mktemp: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: mktemp [-V] | [-dqtu] [-p prefix] [template]
Found these virus scanners installed: clamav
===========================================================================
Filename Checks: Windows/DOS Executable (1 eicar.com)
Other Checks: Found 1 problems
Virus and Content Scanning: Starting
mktemp: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: mktemp [-V] | [-dqtu] [-p prefix] [template]
ERROR: Option --tempdir requires a non-empty string argument
ERROR: Can't parse command line options
===========================================================================

If any of your virus scanners (clamav)
are not listed there, you should check that they are installed correctly
and that MailScanner is finding them correctly via its virus.scanners.conf.
```

There seems to be error. How will I fix it?

Comment: Try to restart postfix and clamav services.

Comment: @Overmind - Thank you but I have done that. What more shall I do?

Comment: Try a test file like this to see if the AV catches it: https://www.eicar.org/?page_id=3950